# xcode console run log missing Crashlytics "Completed report submission"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I integrated Firebase Crashlytics into my app and added -FIRDebugEnabled to enable debug mode and simulated a crash but my log is missing "Completed report submission" which should be present according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios).
I am already simulating the crash properly-

1. Launch simulator
2. Press stop
3. Launch your app and force a crash
4. Relaunch the app from simulator to report.
   Why is my app not sending crash reports?
   [Picture](https://imgur.com/sRauO0L) of my log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Crashlytics documentation isn't that great. After digging around I realized that installing through Cocoapods vs SPM has a few differences- The run script should be "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run" if Cocoapods is being used. Also pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics' should be present in the podfile which isn't clearly mentioned.